# Пунктуация в предложении с союзом «на случай(,) если»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

*Разумеется, нёс ее сюда кто-то другой, явно большой и сильный, сейчас, вероятнее всего, подпиравший дверь или просто ошивавшийся поблизости(**?**) на случай, если блохастая шкура захочет выкинуть какой-нибудь фокус.*

Требуется ли в этом предложении запятая перед "на случай"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**НА** (ТОТ) **СЛУЧАЙ**(,) **ЕСЛИ**, *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_451)
Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом ***на (тот) случай(,) если***, выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми.
При этом союз может целиком входить в придаточную часть и не разделяться запятой (если слово **тот** отсутствует), но **чаще расчленяется** (в этом случае запятая ставится между частями союза, перед словом **если**).

*«A propos, – сказал я, – чтоб не забыть, – сколько бы взяли вы за вашего крокодила, **на случай если** б вздумали у вас его покупать?»* (Ф. Достоевский); *Он сделал это **на случай, если** будут оцеплять парк, — отсюда он уже мог уйти при всех условиях* (А. Фадеев).

При наличии слова **тот** союз расчленяется, запятая ставится перед словом **если**.

С наречием **сейчас** правильно использовать причастия не прошедшего времени (*подпиравший* и *ошивавшийся*), а настоящего — *подпирающий* и *ошивающийся*.
Перед "на случай" запятая не нужна (так как она уже имеется перед "если").

*Разумеется, нёс ее сюда кто-то другой, явно большой и сильный, сейчас, вероятнее всего, подпирающий дверь или просто ошивающийся поблизости **на случай, если** блохастая шкура захочет выкинуть какой-нибудь фокус.*

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ, хотя я предпочёл бы союз в данном предложении не расчленять.

Comment: Благодарю за поддержку. Я ответила собственно про нужность-ненужность запятой и указала на **явные** ошибки. Конечно, можно еще порассуждать про перегруженность предложения вводными словами, о том, что его лучше разделить на две части, потому что смысл трудно воспринимается, а также о нерасчленимости союза. Но ведь вопрос о глобальной корректуре не стоял.